# I have created a Staff table. It has a self reference key

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table STAFF
(
     StaffID    TINYINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
     StaffName  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     Phone      varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     Gender     char(01),
     DoB        date NOT NULL,
     Mentor     TINYINT,
     Payment_ID TINYINT NOT NULL,

     constraint staff_pk primary key (StaffID),
     constraint staff_fk 
         foreign key (Payment_ID) references PAYMENT(Payment_ID),
     constraint mentor_fk 
         foreign key (Mentor) references staff(StaffID)
);
```

Table was created successfully. But when I'm going to insert values like this:

```
insert into STAFF
values ('Adeesha', '077282018', 'M', '1997-11-30', '', '5'),
       ('Kavitha', '0772556899', 'F', '1956-11-28', '', '4'),
       ('Patee Aiya', '0775669844', 'M', '1954-01-04', '', '3'),
       ('Chanuka', '0772562984', 'M', '1997-02-24', '', '2'),
       ('Umesha', '0723328284', 'F', '1997-11-26', '', '3');
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "mentor_fk".
>   The conflict occurred in database "F_T", table "dbo.STAFF", column 'StaffID'.

Comment: First, TINYINT seems like a poor choice for a key. Second, you need to insert the mentor first. You cannot insert anyone with a mentor filled out, unless you have already inserted the mentor. If the mentor ALSO has a mentor, you'll need to insert THAT mentor first, on up the chain until you are inserting someone with no mentor (NULL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty string (`''`) is not the same as `NULL`.  You should use `NULL`:

```
insert into STAFF(StaffName, Phone, Gender, DoB, Mentor, Payment_ID)
    values ('Adeesha', '077282018', 'M', '1997-11-30', NULL, 5),
           ('Kavitha', '0772556899', 'F', '1956-11-28', NULL, 4),
           ('Patee Aiya', '0775669844', 'M', '1954-01-04', NULL, 3),
           ('Chanuka', '0772562984', 'M', '1997-02-24', NULL, 2),
           ('Umesha', '0723328284', 'F', '1997-11-26', NULL, 3);
```

Notes:

- When using `insert`, list all the columns being inserted into the table.  This is a best-practice.
- Do not insert into the `identity` column.  It is generated automatically.
- Use `NULL` to mean `NULL` rather than an empty string.  They are not the same.
- If a value is a number, do not enclose it in single quotes.